# How to apply thermal grease using a paper template

Tags: cpu, fan, heatsink

I purchased thermal grease that came with a paper template. The tutorial told me to apply the grease to the template and then attach it to the fan base (heatsink), and then remove the paper and join it with the CPU.

Do I need to apply any grease to the top of the CPU, or are the instructions correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions are correct.  The thermal grease will adhere to the CPU when you attach the heatsink, so there is no need to put any grease on the CPU itself.

Comment: But there is paper layer between CPU and heat sink

Comment: Remove the paper after using it to apply the grease to the heatsink (fan base). There shouldn't be anything but a thin layer of grease between the heatsink and the CPU. When you attach the heatsink to the CPU and clamp it down, it will make a very tight seal to transfer heat from the CPU to the heatsink, which is cooled by the fan.

Answer (score 1):

There are several videos that show the different ways of applying the thermal grease/compound

- [Installing thermal compound](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRRWbQUqW1Y)
- [Applying Arctic Silver](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xekr6eQL62U)
- [How to spread thermal grease](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aU2_uP9S9Gg)